# Asp.net LinkButton, set visibility

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following asp.net setup:

```
<tr runat="server" id="trDecline" class="even">
    <td class="adminrow-name">Decline Applicant:</td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="lnkDecline">Click Here</a>
        <div class="divDecline" style="display:none;">
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddDeclineReason" CssClass="ddDeclineReason" DataTextField="StatusDetail" DataValueField="ProposalStatusDetailID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddDeclineApplicant_Selected" AutoPostBack="true"/>  <br>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" visible="false" ID="btnApplicantDecline" Text="Decline" ValidationGroup="declineApplicantButton" onClick="btnDecline_Applicant_Click" />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

where I set the visibility of the `LinkButton` using `visible="false"`

Then, when someone selects an item from the `dropdown`, I want the `LinkButton` to become visible.

I have the following `listener` setup on the `dropdown`:

```
public void ddDeclineApplicant_Selected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(btnApplicantDecline.visible);
    Response.End();
}
```

The problem is, I get the following error:

> System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton' does not contain a definition for 'visible' and no extension method 'visible' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

But how can this be the case, as I am setting the property, andi t is working.

How can I set the visibility of this programatically if I cant use this control?

I know I can use CSS, but I want to keep within the existing framework of the project.

My google searches have not yielded any results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change "visible" for "Visible". V is UpperCase.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

You can see that Visible turn color to blue,because it have to be UpperCase

```
<tr runat="server" id="trDecline" class="even">
        <td class="adminrow-name">Decline Applicant:</td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="lnkDecline">Click Here</a>
            <div class="divDecline" style="display:none;">
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddDeclineReason" CssClass="ddDeclineReason" DataTextField="StatusDetail" DataValueField="ProposalStatusDetailID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddDeclineApplicant_Selected" AutoPostBack="true"/>  <br>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Visible="false" ID="btnApplicantDecline" Text="Decline" ValidationGroup="declineApplicantButton" onClick="btnDecline_Applicant_Click" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```